# Global delaration of variables in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Here are two code examples of global delarations:

```
var globalVariable = 'something';
```

and

```
globalVariable = 'something';
```

Whats the difference between those solutions or does it even have one? Which one is the better solution? Should I avoid one of those solutions? And if yes, why?

**EDIT: both of them are defined in a global level.**

Comment: Declared in the global context, i.e. under `window` in a browser, they are the same, but it's good practice to always use the `var` statement so as not to forget it elsewhere and unintentionally create globals.

Answer (score 4):

When you omit the keyword `var`, it makes the variable automatically global, irrespective of where it is defined. So, even if it is defined within a function, it will be visible everywhere

So, second option `globalVariable = 'something';` makes it global.

Where as the first option `var globalVariable = 'something';` will only be global if it is defined at a global level. If this is defined within a function for instance, it will be visible only to that function.

It is advisable to avoid declaring global variable unless necessary.

More about scoping here - http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp

Comment: You might not want to link to w3schools here, some of us are really against it. Visit http://w3fools.com/ to see why...

Comment: A good explanation of the `var` keywords is here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var

Answer (score 2):

The first is only a global declaration if you place it in the global scope but, in general, if you want a global variable then you should explicitly declare it in the global scope (even if you only assign a value to it later).

The second will always create a global variable.

That said, you should avoid both options. You almost never really need global variables. In cases where it is useful to have a global, it is usually better to wrap your script in a IIFE and have your variables declared at that level.

```
(function () {
    var not_quite_a_global;

    function foo() {
        not_quite_a_global = 1;
    }
}());
```

That stops them conflicting with other variables, with the same name, from other scripts or modules loaded at the same time.